# Android Universal Image Loader store downloaded progress listview

Tags: android, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I am using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in ListView. My problem is with following usecase:

when I scroll on listview,it works perfectly, and load all images. Lets suppose, I have 2 items on screen in listview, they are in download progress. I can see it's progress by `ImageLoadingProgressListener()`, as soon as i scroll anywhere and come back to same images, THE PROGRESS STARTS AGAIN, Previously  downloaded data lost!! Is there any way to store that downloaded progress so that it can resume that process later when we come back to that image in listview.

Edit: I can cache those images once they downloaded, and also able to use those cached image, My problem is with THAT TIME WHEN THAY ARE BEING DOWNLOADED , SCROLL AND COME BACK.

My `DisplayImageOptions`:

```
options =  new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(100))
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .build();
```

My `ImageLoaderConfiguration`:

```
new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024) // 50 Mb
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
                .build();
```

My `getView()`:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card, parent,false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.ivContent = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivContent);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try {
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, holder.ivContent, options, new        SimpleImageLoadingListener(){
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,Bitmap loadedImage){
                    holder.ivContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            },
            new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressUpdate(String arg0, View arg1, int count, int total) {
                    System.out.println("prog: "+(count*100)/total);
                    //holder.ivLoaderUp.setClipping((count*100)/total);
                }
            });
         }   
         catch (ParseException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return convertView;
   }
```

Has anyone run into this problem, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can found the answer why loadings are started again - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27154307/913762). UIL abort downloading if there is loaded less than 75% of image data. If you want to change it then you should change the sources of `IoUtil` class. Change constant from:

```
public static final int CONTINUE_LOADING_PERCENTAGE = 75;
```

to

```
public static final int CONTINUE_LOADING_PERCENTAGE = 0;
```

Comment: The solution has worked for me! Thanks much. Suggestions :1) It would be nice to have some Setter method here. 2) My usecase: If we scroll then, that progress stops(saved) and another begins. when we come back, it resumes. Anyway, we appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Use latest version of Image loader library but i recommend you to try Smart image you just have to download library from following URL
**http://www.4shared.com/folder/iw0vL8m6/_online.html**
place this jar file in your Android app’s libs/ folder.

Add a SmartImageView to your activity’s xml layout:

```
<com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image" />
```

And in your `Activity`

```
SmartImageView myImage = (SmartImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
```

Load an image into the view from a URL:

```
myImage.setImageUrl("http://www.YOUR_URL/myawesomeimage.jpg");
```

its the best one i did use Image loader but this library is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try AQuery for this.

You can download the jar file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list), Download the jar file and set jar to your Build Path.

```
 AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);
```

As an example to load image directly from url:

```
androidAQuery.id(ucover).image(user_pro, true, true); // Here, true, true means fileCache and MemoryCache respectively. So you can store it in memory or in file, so each and every time it will not downloaded.
```

Comment: I would definitely like to try this, but if you have any suggestions regarding UIL, Appreciated !

Comment: Nop, I have never used, because its not good in all cases, but AQuery is vast, so I never used it, so no idea about UIL.